# Overriding container JRE while deployment

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The images are built up using Oracle Open JDK reference.
So, when we bring the container up, it uses the same Oracle Open JDK.

We want to provide a facility so that JRE can be changed while deployment. If any user don't want to change then it will work with provided default Oracle Open JDK.

One possible solution we thought:
We will change our docker-compose to volume map a host customJRE directory to container as containerJRE.
We will change our project Dockerfile once which can set JAVA_HOME and PATH variables to refer containerJRE. And we will rebuild the image once.
While deployment, Users will provide their own JRE on host machines.
So, when container comes up, this custom JRE would be used.

We would like to know the disadvantages of this approach before going further.
If there are any better approach or improvements in this would also be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to construct a base image using a custom JRE. This base image should take care of setting `JAVA_HOME` and updating path.

Later you can create an app docker image by extending the above custom JRE base image.

Disadvantages with your current approach

1. Increased overall image size and container size as it would have unused Oracle JRE binaries
2. Overhead of maintaining volume
3. Overhead of maintaining extra steps you are going to perform to override existing JRE with an external one
4. Overhead of recreating docker image

Comment: Thank you Yogesh for your feedback. I agree on your points as we also thought of same initially.

Actually, we have multiple images with us. Which users will be using. The important point is, we want to have images one default JRE [Oracle Open JDK]. So if users don't have their specific JRE then they won't have to do anything. That is the reason we thought of this approach.

Here, we would like to know if this can cause any sort of issues later or anything we need to keep in mind.

I will update the description with additional information.

Comment: We went ahead with the initial design and not seeing any issues so far. Of-course we added some level of additional complexity. But the kind of requirement we had, we had to go for it. Thank you David and Yogesh for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image generally contains a complete runnable filesystem; you can't usually swap out components like libraries or base images like the JRE.

If it's important to your application that the end user be able to select the JRE, then a Docker-based packaging that bundles a fixed JRE isn't what you want.  Distributing a jar file probably isn't going to be significantly more complex and I would suggest that approach.

If you're encouraging users to use a pre-built Docker image but then bind-mount their choice of JRE over what's in the system, it's almost a guaranteed support nightmare.  You'll find Windows and Mac users trying to mount their host JRE into a Linux container and getting strange failures.  Some users will typo the path and use the standard JRE and get unexpected behavior.  Some JREs just might be incompatible.  Either the in-container JRE or the host JRE might not be self-contained within a single directory and so attempts to replace it could wind up with a weird mix of JRE versions.  It will be your responsibility to support all of this when users have questions or problems.

Comment: Thank you David for your feedback. I completely agree on all of your points. In our case, we have developed microservice based architecture and it is getting bigger. There are reasons we can't go away from containers. And we are also sure that there will not be any human error in providing JRE on host machine, considering the kind of users/customers we have. We are just trying to provide a facility so that users/customers won't have to request us back to use their own licensed JRE.